Why does Oracle think that a strong reference cursor is not correctly declared?
I’m trying to create some stored procedures, one of which accepts a strong reference cursor as a parameter.  Although I think I’ve correctly specify the strong reference cursor I encounter an error when I attempt to create a unit test for this stored procedure.
The following commands were executed by SYSTEM:

    CREATE USER HR IDENTIFIED BY HR;
    grant CREATE session to hr;
    grant create any procedure to HR;
    the following is how I connect to Oracle via sqlplus:
    sqlplus hr/HR@connectionstring:7152 

contents of create_emp_table.sql:

DROP TABLE "HR"."EMP";
CREATE TABLE "HR"."EMP"
(
  EMPNO            NUMBER(4)                             PRIMARY KEY,
  ENAME            VARCHAR2(10),                                  
  JOB              VARCHAR2(9),                                   
  MGR              NUMBER(4),                                     
  HIREDATE         DATE,                                          
  SAL              NUMBER(7,2),                                   
  COMM             NUMBER(7,2),                                   
  DEPTNO           NUMBER(2)                                     
);
END;


SQL> @create_emp_table.sql

Table dropped.
Table created.


SQL>  @create_pkgbdy_hr.plb

Package body created.

SQL> @create_pkgbdy_hr-child.plb
Sequence dropped.
Sequence created.
Package body created.
Contents of create_pkgbdy_hr.plb:

CREATE sequence  employees_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY hr_child
IS

-- Read all employee details
   PROCEDURE get_all_emp_details(
                                   p_details IN OUT hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t
                                )   
IS    BEGIN

  --
  OPEN p_details FOR
     SELECT *
     FROM   emp;
  --
END;

--
various procedures redacted
END;
/


Contents of create_pkg_hr-child.pls follows.
Note that  empl_details_refcur_t is a strong reference cursor based on the emp table

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE hr_child
IS
   --
   TYPE empl_details_refcur_t IS REF CURSOR RETURN emp%ROWTYPE;   
   TYPE dept_details_refcur_t IS REF CURSOR RETURN dept%ROWTYPE;
   --===========================================================
various procedures redacted
END;
/

SQL>  @create_pkgbdy_hr.plb
Package body created.

    --
    -- contents of create_pkgbdy_hr.plb follows:
    --
    CREATE OR REPLACE
    PACKAGE BODY hr
    IS
       --
    various procedures redacted   --
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       --
       -- obtain details for all employees
       --
       PROCEDURE employees_r(
                               p_details IN OUT hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t
                            )
       IS
       BEGIN
          --
          OPEN p_details FOR
             SELECT *
             FROM   emp;
          --
          --
       END;
    various procedure redacted   --
    END;
    /

SQL>  @create_pkg_hr.pls
Package created.
Contents of create_pkg_hr.pls follows:
    --
    -- hr.pls
    
    -- The "CRUD indicator" is a letter following the last underscore in
    -- the procedure's name.  In this package the various procedures
    -- that affect the employee table are:
    --
    --    employees_c()  -- create an employee
    --    employees_r()  -- read employee details
    --    employees_u()  -- update  employee details
    --    employees_d()  -- destroy an employee
    --
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE
    PACKAGE hr
    IS
       --
       --===========================================================
       --
       -- emp
       --
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    various procedures redacted
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       --
       -- Read all emp' details
       --
       PROCEDURE employees_r(
                                 p_details    IN OUT  hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t
                              );
       --
    various procedures redacted    --
    END;
    /


OK the emp table is created and the packages built without error. Now create a unit test.
ut_hr.sql follows:
    -- unittest
    --

    SET serverout ON
    SET linesize 300
    COLUMN name FORMAT A30
    CREATE OR REPLACE
    PROCEDURE read_employee
        IS
    
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
            io          hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t;  
            v_retcode   NUMBER := NULL;
    
        BEGIN
            hr.employees_r(io);
        END;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_employee_id,   '  || '(' || TO_CHAR( io.EMPNO)    || ')' );
    END;
    /

    SQL> @ut_hr.sql
    LINE/COL ERROR
    -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
    12/5     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    12/66    PLS-00201: identifier 'IO.EMPNO' must be declared

so it appears that empno is not part of hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t;
because hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t is a strong ref cursor it should match the columns in the emp table

    SQL> desc emp
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- -------
     EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
     ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
     JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
     MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
     HIREDATE                                           DATE
     SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
     COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
     DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
    
    SQL>


empno is a column in the emp table. So why must 'IO.EMPNO' must be
declared?

In the HR package, you SELECT * FROM employees; but there is no employees table - it is called EMP.

Also, please put the code in the correct order so that it compiles. The package signature should be before the package body. (And remove the whitespace at the start of the lines and the comments about redacted lines so that it can be copy-pasted and compiles)

@MTO ouch! I overlooked that the table's name was actually emp.  nice catch!

The scope where the IO variable was declared has ended and, in the outer scope of the procedure there is no IO variable.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_employee
IS 
      -- Declare section for outer scope
BEGIN -- Begin outer scope
  DECLARE -- Declare section for inner scope
    io          hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t;  
    v_retcode   NUMBER := NULL;
  BEGIN   -- Begin inner scope
    hr.employees_r(io);
  END;    -- End inner scope
      -- Continue outer scope
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_employee_id,   '  || '(' || TO_CHAR( io.EMPNO)    || ')' );
END;
/

To fix it, remove the inner PL/SQL block and move everything to the outer block. Once you do that you also need to fix that IO is a cursor and is not a row from the table and a cursor does not have column attributes so IO.EMPNO does not exist - to get the row you need to loop through the cursor and fetch the row and then row.EMPNO will exist:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_employee
IS 
  io hr_child.empl_details_refcur_t;  
  rw EMP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  hr.employees_r(io);
  LOOP
    FETCH io INTO rw;
    EXIT WHEN io%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_employee_id, (' || rw.EMPNO || ')' );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE io;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF io%ISOPEN THEN
      CLOSE io;
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/

fiddle

@MTO, that cracked my problerm.  Many thanks, I am grateful for your help
